# One and the same onclick event works on one page, but not on another; Console says Uncaught ReferenceError: is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick, buttonclick

I'm really at a loss here; tried anything and everything, to no avail.

I'm implementing several forms on a few websites; for all of them, I want to disable the submit button until a person has checked the "Privacy Policy" checkbox. I created a function that actually works: I already implemented one form on each of these websites, and in all cases the function for the button works as expected.

Now I'm trying to implement one more form on one of these websites, and when published, the button doesn't work, and the console says that the function is not defined (Uncaught ReferenceError: enableSubmitButton is not defined).

[Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2lCv.png)

[Sources screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q8OW.png)

And I cannot understand what the problem is. I ran the code with the W3Schools editor – it works fine there. When I insert the code through a visual editor (the website is on Wordpress, the editor is Cornerstone), it works there too. Not on the front-end, though. I tried renaming the function, it didn't help. And so I just don't know what else to do. Can you please help me spot the problem?

Here's my code:

**This is where I introduce onclick event:**

```
<div class='zcwf_row'><div class='zcwf_privacy'><div class='dIB vat' align='left'><input type='checkbox' name='privacyTool' onclick='enableSubmitButton(this)'></div><div class='dIB zcwf_privacy_txt'>By submitting your data, you agree to their transfer, storing or processing as stated in our Privacy Policy.</div></div></div><div class='zcwf_row'><div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='submit' id='formsubmit' class='formsubmit zcwf_button' value='Send' title='Send' disabled><input type='reset' style='visibility:hidden; ' class='zcwf_button' name='reset' value='Reset' title='Reset'></div></div>
```

**This is where I defined the function:**

```
<script>
    function enableSubmitButton(termsCheckBox){
        //If the checkbox has been checked
        if(termsCheckBox.checked){
            //Set the disabled property to FALSE and enable the button.
            document.getElementById("formsubmit").disabled = false;
        } 
        else{
            //Otherwise, disable the submit button.
            document.getElementById("formsubmit").disabled = true;
        }
   }
</script>
```

**This is the complete form** (stripped of the most styling and number of fields shortened to minimum to keep it simple here). Please ignore the strange structure, it's Zoho Webforms, nothing I can do about it except for lots of restyling.

```
<style>
    html,body{
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #crmWebToEntityForm.zcwf_lblTopBottom * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    #crmWebToEntityForm{
        text-align: left;
    }
    #crmWebToEntityForm * {
        direction: ltr;
    }
    .zcwf_lblTopBottom .zcwf_col_fld_inline input[type=text] {
        border: 1px solid #EEEEEE!important;
        resize: vertical;
        border-radius: 3px;
        float: left;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .zcwf_lblTopBottom .zcwf_col_fld_inline {
        width: 50%!important;
        padding: 0px 6px 0px;
        position: relative;
        float:left;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    .zcwf_lblTopBottom .zcwf_privacy{
        padding: 6px!important;

    }
    .zcwf_lblTopBottom .wfrm_fld_dpNn{
        display: none;
    }
    .dIB{
        display: inline-block;
        max-width:90%!important;
    }
    .zcwf_lblTopBottom .zcwf_row_inline:after {
        content: '';
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
    .zcwf_lblTopBottom .zcwf_row_inline {
        margin: 0px 0px;
    }
    .zcwf_lblTopBottom .formsubmit {
        margin-right: 5px!important;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #fff!important;
        font-size: 18px!important;
    }
    .zcwf_lblTopBottom .formsubmit:disabled {
        cursor: not-allowed!important;
    }
    .zcwf_lblTopBottom input[type="submit"]:disabled {
        cursor: not-allowed!important;
        background-color:#E9967A;
    }
    .zcwf_lblTopBottom .zcwf_button {
        margin-top: 2%;
        background-color: red;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    .zcwf_lblTopBottom .zcwf_ckbox{
        float: left;
    }
</style>

<div class='zcwf_row_inline'>
    <div class='zcwf_col_fld_inline'>
            <input type='text' placeholder='First name' id='First_Name' name='First Name' maxlength='40'    style='min-width: 100%!important;'></input>
        <div class='zcwf_col_help'>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='zcwf_col_fld_inline'>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Last name' id='Last_Name' name='Last Name' maxlength='40' style='min-width: 100%!important;'></input>
       <div class='zcwf_col_help'>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='zcwf_row'><div class='zcwf_privacy'><div class='dIB vat' align='left'><input type='checkbox' name='privacyTool' onclick='enableSubmitButton(this)'></div><div class='dIB zcwf_privacy_txt' style='font-size: 16px;font-family:"Oxygen", Open Sans;color:#445265;'>By submitting your data, you agree to their transfer, storing or processing as stated in our Privacy Policy.</div></div></div><div class='zcwf_row'><div class='zcwf_col_fld'><input type='submit' id='formsubmit' class='formsubmit zcwf_button' value='Send' title='Send' disabled><input type='reset' style='visibility:hidden; ' class='zcwf_button' name='reset' value='Reset' title='Reset'></div></div>

<script>
    function enableSubmitButton(termsCheckBox){
        //If the checkbox has been checked
        if(termsCheckBox.checked){
            //Set the disabled property to FALSE and enable the button.
            document.getElementById("formsubmit").disabled = false;
        } 
        else{
            //Otherwise, disable the submit button.
            document.getElementById("formsubmit").disabled = true;
        }
   }
</script>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: try to put the script outside the form tag

Comment: Just tried; no, unfortunately, that didn't change anything, the button is still disabled with or without the checkbox ticked :-(

Comment: This can happen if your `<script>` tag has a syntax error, but you've culled the output, so can't see

Comment: @tim If I remove it, the button appears enabled from the start. I want it to appear disabled from the start. Or is there a way to do that through the function only?

Comment: it should work normally

Comment: @tim doesn't look like this is the problem; I deleted it and nothing changed. Besides, this piece is inherited CSS from Zoho, i.e. nothing I added myself

Comment: @O_Annenko I tried your code, it works on my side. Maybe you should try to switch browser or clear your cache and give it a try again.

Comment: Why do you call it `enableSubmitButton` here, but it's `enableSubmitButtonMio` in the screenshots?

Comment: @tim? That's the weirdest thing – it seems to work in general, it just doesn't work on this particular page, for this particular form. And yeah, I had checked it in Incognito a few times, and I've just just checked it with a completely new browser with a clean cache – it's a nope again :-( My head is exploding...

Comment: Is the page accessible from the Internet, can you give us a link?

Comment: @Barmar my bad, I should have reloaded the page before I did the screenshots. I wanted to see what happens if I rename the function (since there is already one form on the same website that uses this function name – surprise, surprise, renaming the function didn't change anything either).

Comment: @Barmar Absolutely! Here's the form based on the code above: https://www.elastic.io/connector-request/ 
And here is the form that IS actually working, same function, similar code: https://www.elastic.io/plans/#contact-sales

Comment: When I load your page I see a syntax error in the console from this line: `var emailVal = emailFld&#091;i&#093;.value;`

Comment: You have similar errors in other functions.

Comment: You need to replace all the `&#091;` with `[` and `%#093;` with `]`.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know why you get this error, this is not in my code; `&#091;` or `%#093;`are nowhere to be found [link](https://prnt.sc/11rgk9g)

Comment: This is what I see in view-source:https://www.elastic.io/connector-request/ https://prnt.sc/11rgr0a

Comment: @Barmar Now I understand this thing less and less. I clearly see there are no `&#091;`and `%#093;` in the code I submit through the editor; yet my Console shows me the same error that you got.

Comment: Something in your deployment process is converting `[]` to entities.

Comment: @Barmar ...and I don't understand what's different this time. There is nothing that I can think of that is different in the deployment of this form, compared with the deployment of the form that is working (the elastic.io/plans/#contact-sales one). I know you wouldn't know this either, I'm just complaining, sorry!

Comment: UPD: Deleting all the older elements on the page and building the form basically from scratch seems to have resolved the issue. Still, I have no idea what caused it in the first place. I could identify one specific element in the visual editor that seemed to have broken everything (one column, to be precise), however, there was no special styling or JS rules attached to it; it didn't have any hidden classes or anything like that. This is just plain weird... Anyways, it's kinda resolved now.